# MS Access 2010 Modify subform with Listbox multiple seleection

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

**main problem is modification/filtering of subform with listbox (multiple selection) in main form:** 

I managed to do it for a listbox when it is set to "Multi Select: None", however when changed to desired "Multi Select: Simple" it is no longer working (form is empty). I set Master/Child links and I am wondering if it is possible to filter subform with multiple listbox and I need to code something, somewhere? Or simply it is not working in this configuration?

 
For example in listbox I have countries, I want to select all european countries to filter database with Europe.


**Alternatively:** 

The only secodn solution that comes to my mind is to recreate SQL code, every time user selects/unselects fields in listbox and then modify SQL code of query (which is base of subform). I know how to do it but would prefer to avoid this solution if possible. Maybe you have other ideas?


Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to use code, but you don't have to recreate the full SQL query every time the user clicks on a listbox value. All you need to do is create a WHERE clause (without the WHERE) and update the form's `Filter` property. Also, make sure `FilterOn` is set properly.

Comment: I would add a `Continents` table, and populate it with the continents. Then, update your `Countries` table, and add a foreign key to `Continents`. This way, you can effictivly limit your countries to a selected continent.